# WP 5-minute Install Error: "Waiting on Localhost..." ---why does this happen?

Tags: localhost, local-installation

I installed WordPress on localhost using MAMP many times without a problem. Today WordPress froze halfway through a fresh local install and I don't know why.

- Thinking something was out of a date, I updated:
- MAMP to version 4.2
- PHP to v7.1
- After updating MAMP, I upgraded MySQL (prompted by MAMP after upgrade)
- WordPress v4.9.1
- Double-checked database name spelling matches name in ~/sites directory.
- Apache Port 80, tried SQL at 3306 and 8889.

From here, trying the WP install and localhost/SITE-NAME/wp-login.php works fine:

[image]

Alright Sparky we're ready to go:

[image]

After adding Name/Info/Email/etc & clicking "INSTALL", the page hangs here with a message in the bottom left corner of the screen: "Waiting on Localhost...", it doesn't time out and the page-load icon never stops spinning.

[image]
It just stays on this screen 'loading'. (I cut the names/emails out of the screenshot, these images makes them look invisible. They are there.)
I think I overlooked something.
Looking around the web I found someone with a similar problem:

- [Problem Installing WordPress Locally](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/problem-installing-wordpress-locally-2/) (they found a fix, but it doesn't say what answered the problem, only the comment: "its fixed!"

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you know where to find your Apache error log in MAMP? It might have some clues

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It turned out, that PHP gave WordPress too little time to create all tables in the database and fill them with data - I've increased timeout for scripts from 30 to 120 seconds and WordPress installed correctly.